# Translate latitude/longitude to point on svg map

Tags: javascript, svg, google-maps-api-3, cartography

Given an svg map like [this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:USA_Counties_with_names.svg) on Wikimedia, I'd like to add a circle centered on New York City (or any given latitude/longitude) by adding a line like this to the svg file:

```
<circle cx="X" cy="Y" r="5" />
```

The hard part of course is knowing what `X` and `Y` should be. New York's latitude and longitude are 40.7127° N, 74.0059° W. Is there a way to convert this to an x,y coordinate that is consistent with the given svg file? The file doesn't say what projection was used, so I imagine this can only be done by guessing what the projection is.

Comment: You might want to look at http://kartograph.org - that will help you with placing points if you know the projection. You don't, but you could guess some common ones.